# Debian - unattended installation

Tags: linux, debian, unattended

Is there any way to make the installation of Debian unattended, I need to install on multiple machines with similar hardware.

Basically I need to install Debian system without human interaction, with predefined parameters such as users and passwords.

Comment: How similar is the hardware? You might be able to use clonezilla and a drbl server.

Comment: I wondered the same thing, apparently has nice features and options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can do that using Debian's "preseeding" system which is based on the deb-conf engine.

read here:
https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/i386/apbs02.html.en

Basically you create a preseed file that the install system retrieves at boot time reading a series of parameters/variables that correspond to the inputs required by the Debian interactive install system (deb-conf).
If the preseed file has a particular variable in it the corresponding interactive parameter request is just skipped taking the value from the pressed file.
You can define "all" the install required parameters then you get a Debian fully unattended install.

[Debian Preseed Reference.](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed)

Comment: ill do some test but i think this is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can go the route of `FAI`, "Fully Automated Installation" which is specifically designed for multiple repetitive installs. See [the website](http://fai-project.org/) for details.

Comment: I'll also check it, seem insteresting.

Comment: Why would I learn a new tool for doing what Debian already natively (perfectly) does...

Answer (score 0):

Google for "Debian preseeding". It usually involves setting up a DHCP/DNS/TFTP/HTTP server combination, serving addresses, names, basic boot files and preseed files. You can skip all but the last with a bootable usb stick with mini iso but with a local preseed file.

Comment: the point of the community is get a right answer or some references, not only a Google for...